# How to share a referal code and playstore app with friends

Tags: java, android

1.I register in my app, on registering successful a referral code will be generated.

2.I want to share my appPlaystore's link along with the referral code to my friends through text/Whatsapp/email.

3.Once they click the playstore link Serverside should be able to know that they are using my referral code and my referral count should be increased.

(eg.share link through swiggy to friends)

**(Please click the numbers hyperlink below to view the images****strong text**

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJyfW.jpg) share a invite link of my app with referral code like the image given first][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FieW4.jpg)
[Have to [Clicking the link it gets redirecrted to a browser and where the server saves the information of referal code and the person who send the link
Then it moves to playstore and the app gets installed and the person who share the link gets or rewarded with some coupons.this what i want to do.

Comment: what is this about?

Comment: What exacly you want to do ?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow; your question is not very informative maybe you can go through this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to find more about how to format your question and the corresponding process.

From what I can tell you can use [Play Install Referrer Api](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/igetinstallreferrerservice) which is used for the same use-case.

Comment: Have you used google pay.if i want to share the google pay app link to my friends i will send the app playstore link via sms with referral code.Do you have an idea about it.